# std::tuple assignment and copy/move exception guarantees

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

I don't see anything on subj in current draft. Do I get it right, that the following code

```
struct Omg { Omg &operator=(Omg const &o) { throw 0; } };

std::tuple t0{42, Omg{}};
std::tuple t1{10, Omg{}};
t1 = t0;
```

is fully allowed to leave t1 in semi-assigned state? I.e., its first element could have already changed yet the second one can remain as it was, or even become inconsistent?

Comment: Wouldn't that be the case for every overloaded assignment operator that throws?

Comment: @PlinyTheElder No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is fully allowed to leave t1 in semi-assigned state?

Yes. [Copy-assignment](http://eel.is/c++draft/tuple#assign-2) is specified as just:

> *Effects:* Assigns each element of `u` to the corresponding element of `*this`.

There are other types in the standard library that *do* specify an exception guarantee (e.g. `optional`), but `tuple` does not provide one.

Note that it doesn't specify an ordering to the assignment. An implementation could assign the `Omg` first (so no change to `t1`) or the `int` first (so you end up with a semi-assigned state).

I think an implementation could also choose to do copy-and-swap and thus provide a strong exception guarantee. That would match the specified effects. But this is not guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: Copy-and-swap would do nothing to this situation unless types are nothrow swappable.

Comment: I don't think copy and swap is legal.  Exept maybe as-if.